# Performance of Linux software raid-1 across SSD and HDD (partitions)

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, ssd

How does Linux software raid-1 work across disks of dissimilar performance.

Would a raid-1 across ssd and hdd partitions give me a mirror of the ssd contents while not impacting the read speed?  I only need good read speed.

Or will it just distribute "reads" round-robin between the drives, giving poor read performance?

(I understand and accept that write performance will be as slow as a hdd.)

Comment: How do you create that raid1? LVM or MDADM?

Comment: I am familiar with mdadm.  Are there TRIM problems with 'nested' SSDs?

Answer (score 4):

From the [mdadm-developer-blog](http://neil.brown.name/blog/mdadm) I would say - you need at least the 3.2.1 version with that policy-stuff. This sounds as if you can define one member as `spare` instead of using it for active reading/writing. So in your case the harddisk should be the spare.